# How to get the exact value from a column with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the value from a column in a mysql table. The value from the mysql row is a simple number of 2 figures. (40) I tried:

```
$healthh = intval(mysql_query("SELECT health FROM users 
           WHERE username = ".quote_smart($username).""));
```

and in `print_r($healthh);` I get 33 instead of 40.

tried also

```
$healthh = mysql_query("SELECT health FROM users 
           WHERE username = ".quote_smart($username)."");
```

OUTPUT IS in this case Resource id #33

if i try like this:

```
$healthh = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT health FROM users 
           WHERE username = ".quote_smart($username).""));
```

I get the right value but not as an integer (a simple 2 figure number)
OUTPUT: `stdClass Object ( [health] => 40 )`

Any ideas?

Comment: @downvoter may I know what is the down vote for?

Comment: You're trying to parse the result set. You need to fetch a row from your resultset first, and get the data from that - `mysql_fetch_assoc`, or something similar.

Comment: As you're obviously a beginner in this field 2 other pieces of advice: mysql_* calls are deprecated, do not base any new development on them, use mysqli or PDO.  Next, `quote_smart` suggests that you are trying to solve quoting problems and security issues in SQL the wrong way.  Visit [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/) to learn about SQL injection, and also there, learn about the *proper* way to avoid quoting issues and SQL injection dangers.

Comment: Please, before you get yourself into serious trouble, do not use the `mysql_query` interface. It's being removed from future versions of PHP because it's so problematic. If you're doing queries like this, you probably need a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) so you're not spending your time fussing with low-level SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql_fetch_asoc()

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT health FROM users 
       WHERE username = ".quote_smart($username)."");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$healthh = $row['health'];
```